# Reverse power transformation in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

If I am doing $3^4$ which equals $81$, what transformation do I have to apply to $81$ to get the $3$ back?

I can take a log base $3$ to get $4$. But I need to do a transformation against the $81$ to get the $4$ back. I apologize if this is a silly question but none of the log rules I found addressed this I'm sure there's some algebra that can be done to get the answer but I'm struggling with how

Comment: You want to extract the fourth root or, equivalently, to raise to the $\frac 14$ power.

Comment: Assuming we are working with positive real numbers, $a^b=c \iff a=c^{1/b}$.

Comment: If you want to use logarithms then  $a^b=c \iff b\log_e(a)=\log_e(c) \iff \log_e(a)=\frac1b\log_e(c) \iff a=\exp\left(\frac1b\log_e(c)\right) \iff  a=c^{1/b}$